# Why .offsetParent returns nearest table for non-positioned element

Tags: javascript, html, css

From [the MDN documentation for `Element.offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent):

> The `HTMLElement.offsetParent` read-only property returns a reference to the object which is the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned containing element. **If the element is non-positioned, the nearest table, table cell or root element is returned by offsetParent**

Why does `.offsetParent` return the nearest table if the element is not positioned (that is, `position: static`)? Why doesn't `.offsetParent` always return the nearest positioned element?

I know that the answer to my question is "because the standard says so," but why did the developers of the standard decide that? What is the purpose of that behavior?

Comment: Because setting table cells out of the text flow is problematic. Ofcourse the statement stands only for elements inside a cell.

Comment: @Teemu "setting table cells out of the text flow is problematic". Usually. But not necessarily with `position: sticky` (now available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs *were* at best misleading, or mislead.

The new version is clearer:

> A positioned ancestor is either:
>
> - an element with a non-static position, or
> - `td`, `th`, `table` in case the element itself is static positioned.

So, `.offsetParent` does "return the nearest positioned element", if there is one before the nearest `td`, `th`, or `table`:

```js
console.log("in positioned", target1.offsetParent);
console.log("in static", target2.offsetParent);
```

```css
.positioned { position: relative }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class=positioned>
          <span id=target1>content</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class=static>
          <span id=target2>content</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As for why they decided these elements should be treated as positioned elements even though their computed `position` is `"static"`, it's certainly because their position is actually dictated by rules that doesn't match *static*'s rules.